# Room: Conflicting Declarations

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I would like to add value, date and details to the current pb. I am receiving an error 'conflicting declaration' in the database for pbInfo. How should I fix this error?

```
@Entity(tableName = "pb_table")
data class Pb(@PrimaryKey
              val pb: String)

@Entity
data class PbInfo(@PrimaryKey
                  var value: Double,
                  var date: Int,
                  var details: String)
```

```
@Dao
interface PbInfoDao {


    @Insert
    fun update(vararg pbInfo: PbInfo): LongArray
```

```
 INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                    scope.launch {
                        populateDatabase(database.pbDao(), database.pbInfo())
                    }
                }
            }
            suspend fun populateDatabase(pbDao: PbDao, pbInfoDao: PbInfoDao) {
                pbDao.deleteAll()

                var pb = Pb("Squat")
                pbDao.insert(pb)
                var pbInfo = PbInfo(122.5, 28, "I was feeling on top form today!")
```

Comment: why didn't you set a table-name for Pbinfo ?

Comment: I think I know how to solve this, but I don't know Kotlin syntax, cause you know i'm already using multiple tables for a single room-database

Comment: @Psycho I'll add that now. If you know java then I could try to convert it.

Comment: Multiple Entity declaration in a single class.... adding possible solution as answer, wait a bit

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have two Entities in a single class (possibly the conflict)

So, add separate class for separate `Entity`.

Then, in your RoomDatabase abstract class, add two Entity Classes like this (and also create separate `Dao` interface classes):

```
@Database(entities = [(Pb::class), (Pbinfo::class)] ,version = 2)
abstract class YourRoomDatabaseClass: RoomDatabase(){
    ...
     abstract fun pbDao() : PbDao
     abstract fun pbinfoDao(): PbinfoDao
    ...
}
```

This should solve the conflicting of Entity classes. I have a single database with two Entities just like this and running without any problems. (Please mind me because I don't know Kotlin Syntax)

Comment: Thanks, i've tried it all but unfortunately i'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: can you add your logcat please ? @SKdev

Comment: I went to add logcat but surprised it worked on the emulator yet when I rebuild the project which is what I was doing before I still have the following errors: Conflicting declarations: var pbInfo: PbInfo, var pbInfo: PbInfo 
Conflicting declarations: var pbInfo: PbInfo, var pbInfo: PbInfo 
Conflicting declarations: var pbInfo: PbInfo, var pbInfo: PbInfo

> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

Comment: you sure you made separate classes for Pb and Pbinfo in separate files ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197779/discussion-between-psycho-and-skdev).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

instead of

```
@Insert
```

Comment: he is getting conflicting declaration for database entity, not for insertion

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Thanks, I've tried this but the error still remains.